# process Count of each user in ps aux command

Tags: bash, shell-script, ps

How can i create a script to count process run by each user in `ps aux`. I used this

```
ps aux  | awk '{print $1}' | grep root | wc -l
```

but it lists count of root user only . I want to list number of process for each user. I need something like this:

```
root    20
jamshi  15
```

Comment: .[root@server1/]# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME 
root         1  0.0  0.0  19236   180 ?        SNs  Aug15   0:03 
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Aug15   0:00 
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Aug15   0:00
named    31745  0.0  0.6 697276  3236 ?        Ssl  Aug17   0:14 

I need result like below
    =
root 3
named 1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

<strike>`ps -fo user | sort | uniq -c` is worth a try.</strike>

The command `ps -eo user=|sort|uniq -c` will list process counts by user.

```
ps -eo user=|sort|uniq -c
      2 avahi
      1 kernoops
      1 messagebus
      1 nobody
    231 root
      1 statd
      5 steve
      1 syslog
```

If flipping the column order to read   is required, pipe it through `awk '{ print $2 " " $1 }'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply  .[root@server1/]# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME 
root         1  0.0  0.0  19236   180 ?        SNs  Aug15   0:03 
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Aug15   0:00 
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Aug15   0:00
named    31745  0.0  0.6 697276  3236 ?        Ssl  Aug17   0:14 
result of your command
=====
[root@server1 /]# ps -fo user | sort | uniq -c

      4 root
      1 USER

I need result like below
    =
root 3
named 1

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
ps aux |
awk 'NR>1{tot[$1]++;}
     END{for(id in tot)printf "%s %s\n",id,tot[id]}'
```